# Can I travel to Spain with UK ILR and Indian passport?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, spain

I have ILR for the UK and an Indian passport. Can i travel to Spain or other Europe countries?

Answer (score 5):

Citizens of [EU Annex I countries](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/system/files_en?file=2020-09/visa_lists_en.pdf) must possess a visa to enter the territory of a member state. India is an Annex I country. While the citizens of EU Annex II countries (the list appears at the bottom of the document previously linked) may enter without a visa, you are not a citizen of an EU Annex II country.

Spain is a member of the EU. Thus, you must apply for and have received a visa before travel. Because Spain appears to be your principal (or only) destination, you must secure this visa from Spain.

Having UK ILR doesn't allow you to enter the EU without a visa, but will provide some evidence to the visa examiner that you have ties outside of Spain and the EU, and will therefore be more likely to leave on time.

EDIT 2-19-2022

While this Answer speaks of the EU, it would be more accurate to refer to the Schengen Area, as the rules of the Schengen Agreement (not the European Union) control entries and visas to Schengen countries. Schengen incorporates and applies the EU's "Annex" lists.

Comment: It would be more precise to speak of the "Schengen area" rather than "EU" (although EU countries that are officially Schengen candidates -- that is, EU countries other than Ireland -- share the same Annex I and Annex II lists, so being completely precise tends to reduce readability considerably).

Comment: @phoog Yes. I saw that as I was writing. I chose inaccuracy in aid of easer comprehension. I'll add this info as an edit.